# Qt Why use QString::number() over QLocale().toString()?

Tags: qt, type-conversion, tostring, qstring, qlocale

The application I am working on will be launched in many countries and needs to support their language. I've been going back through my code and replacing every instance of:

`QString::number()` and `QString().toDouble()`

with

`QLocale().toString()` and `QLocale().toDouble()`

I haven't found much online comparing the two classes, but I am interested in the repercussions of using the latter, and if there are none - why ever use the `QString` functions?

Essentially I just want to make sure I'm not harming my code before i make all these changes. Does anyone have any knowledge?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `QString` methods are locale-independent: they always happen in the `C` locale. That's useful when the I/O is not localized, e.g. in data files that should be portable across locales and/or machine readable.

You should definitely not haphazardly replace every use of `QString` methods with localized counterparts from `QLocale`! You need to determine which uses should be localized: typically those would include the UI and perhaps some text file I/O where the project specification states that the numeric I/O should be localized. If the spec doesn't mention that, it's worthwhile to amend the spec first, and document the behavior in user-facing documentation too.

Following considerations apply to text I/O.

1. Be permissive with what you accept, and conservative in what you output.
2. Output that is for human consumption and not meant to be machine-readable for data extraction, e.g. PDF and HTML report files, should have localized numbers.
3. Output for machine consumption, e.g. CSV and XML files, should use the C locale.
4. Text input should allow selection of the desired input locale, and should be permissive. E.g. when consuming CSV it helps to use neither `QString::toDouble` nor `QLocale::toDouble` directly on the input, but first to preprocess the input to detect the locale and convert to a fixed C locale, and only then feed it to `QString::toDouble`. E.g.

   ```
   QPair<double, bool> toDouble(QString in) {
     auto dots = in.count('.');
     auto commas = in.count(',');
     if ((dots > 1 && commas > 1) || (dots == 1 && commas ==1))
       // equivocal input
       return qMakePair(0.0, false);
     if (dots > 1 && commas <=1) {
       // dots are group separators
       in.replace(".", "");
       in.replace(',', '.');
     }
     else if (dots <= 1 && commas > 1) {
       // commas are group separators
       in.replace(",", "");
     }
     else if (commas == 1) {
       // assume commas are decimal points
       in.replace(',', '.');
     }
     bool ok;
     auto dbl = in.toDouble(&ok);
     return qMakePair(dbl, ok);
   }
   ```

   In real code you'd want to examine all numbers not in isolation but as a set and make sure that you can detect an unequivocal choice for group separator and decimal point, otherwise you'd have to reject the input.